# The future of Naked Objects pattern (and UI auto-generation)

Tags: user-interface, metaprogramming

I ask about the [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects), not [framework](http://nakedobjects.org). This is kind of follow-up to a question on [UI auto-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445899/is-there-a-library-that-generates-uis-based-on-metadata-declarations-like-this).

1. Do you believe in the concept of UI auto-generation from metadata?
2. What kind of problems can be approached this way?

The question arose when I've created a [small library](http://cliche.sourceforge.net) to support my student projects, which generates interactive CLI in runtime based on object's metadata. And I think CLI it generates is quite decent.

On the other extreme is the [Naked Objects Framework](http://nakedobjects.org), which is rather universal, but UI it generates is horrible, IMO.

It's clear, every problem is specific and needs specific UI, but maybe there are several classes of problems where auto-generation is acceptable?

Comment: Naked Objects is now open source on .net, see  http://nakedobjects.codeplex.com/license

Comment: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~kgajos/research/supple/

Comment: I really wish there was more happening in this area. My whole career I have witnessed people building UIs from scratch in a very unoriginal and repetitive way. We can do better. For many application types the UI is very pattern based so we should be able to automate it. I would say LOB CRUD apps is the prime target.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, I believe the concept of metadata-based auto-generated applications is very sound - mainly because it drastically reduces development time and improves code quality by reducing the massive redundancy you have in most applications where each domain data field is represented in the database, in the model, in the UI, and often also several times in various mapping layers.

I think the future is auto-generated apps that can be modified wherever necessary. Currently, this is AFAIK not really possible; for example, Rails only allows you to fully customize the UI when you use static scaffolding, which basically means code generation, i.e. many further changes in the domain model are then not automatically represented in the UI because the duplication has happened when the code was generated.

I believe the first framework that manages to combine complete auto-generation with complete modifiability afterwards will become the de-facto development standard to a previously unknown degree. Though most likely we'll get there in small steps so that there will not be such a single dominating framework.

Comment: I think "it drastically reduces development time and code quality" should be edited as I don't think it would drastically reduce code quality! Would do it my self but don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Very well said: "the concept... is very sound [but will need a] framework that manages to combine complete auto-generation with complete modifiability afterwards... likely we'll get there in small steps". I would like to humbly offer [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) as just such a small step?

Comment: I look at Haskell and its types+typelevel computation (metaprogramming) combined with referential transparency (strict predictability) topped off with expressiveness.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at JMatter, which is a rather better-looking implementation of Naked Objects.

http://www.jmatter.org

There is also Chris Muller's work on MAUI, and Lukas Renggli's work on Magritte (both Squeak /Smalltalk)

We have lots of generated UI in the configuration part of our apps. All those lists that are around forever and changed once in a blue moon by a system administrator.

I find that most applications with a database back-end tend to have a bad design from an OO and NO perspective, as already shown in the NO book by Pawson and Matthews.

Answer (score 4):

Re: qn #1 ... Do you believe in the concept of UI auto-generation from metadata? ... I'm definitely going to answer 'yes' to your first question, being one of the committers to the Naked Objects (Java) framework and writing a book on DDD + NO.

The question mentions metadata.  I think this is key to NO being able to succeed.  In the latest version (which will be going beta in Feb) the metamodel has been opened up so that it is very extensible, either so you can write your domain model following your own programming conventions/annotations, or, potentially so that more sophisticated viewers can look for their own metadata to provide more sophisticated views.  (For example, consider that if an object implemented a Location interface then it is displayed in a google maps).

Regarding qn #2 ... what kind of problems can be approached this way ... we've always said that NO is more suitable for "sovereign applications" (transactional, operational systems ones used internally within an organization) to "transient applications" (like an airport kiosk, say).  An NO GUI does require that the user is familiar with the domain, otherwise they won't know what they are looking at.

What's missing still is sophisticated viewers, of course.  You are right about the NO GUI, it is definitely low fidelity (though the .NET version is a big improvement, see recent infoq.com article).  On the Java side there is a sister project called scimpi.org that has a lot of promise though... it provides a basic web GUI for free but lets you hand-craft web pages as necessary and incrementally.  I'm also working on an Eclipse RCP GUI that'll work similarly.

The other thing to add to this though is that the NO approach has value (I believe) even if you choose to write a custom GUI and/or presentation layer.  That is, you can use it as a design tool for building a very solid pojo domain layer, and then skin it as you will.  Trouble is that NO was never originally sold in those terms, so most will see the NO pattern as an all-or-nothing affair.

Dan

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at this is to consider the difference between the user interface you get from something like Toad or MySQL Browser, where the user interface is directly constructed from the tables and their associated meta data, and the user interface that a skilled designer would develop for the actual application. IF there not too disimilar then it should be fairly low hanging fruit for an auto-generation framework.

As you say there are classes of problems which will work quite well with this kind of auto generation and some which wouldn't. To my mind the key things are how well the implementation model (or portion thereof) which you are exposing in the user interface maps to the conceptual model of the user. Secondly how well can the behavior of the application can be expressed through a limited set of user interface components (assuming this is a general purpose UI generation framework).

This article "[Universal Model of a User Interface](http://www.baxleydesign.com/pdfs/dux03_baxleyUIModel.pdf)" may be of interest .

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea of automatically generated UIs has a lot of potential especially for your average form-and-table layout database user interface. However, even there a human needs to be in the loop, having the ability to override the output without it being overwritten with the next regeneration.

I suspect automatically generated UIs would be more successful today if interaction designers were more involved in developing the generation algorithms. My impression is that historically the creators of these systems don’t know what kinds of UI-related metadata to include or how to use it. Specifying labels, value ranges, formats, and orders for fields is a start, but more high level information is needed. Sufficient modeling of the tasks and user roles in particular tends to be lacking, along with some basic style-guide-level principles for UI.

Oracle’s Designer 2000, for example, was on the right track in including not only the entities and relations in the model, but also the tasks in the form of a functional hierarchy. Then they blew it by misapplying this metadata (e.g., assuming that depth is always preferred to breadth) and including fundamental flaws when generating the UI (e.g., only one primary window can be opened at a time). The result was IUs that were not even consistent with Oracle’s own Applications User Interface Standards.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a basic UI up **quickly** that lets the customer try out the system and **create test data** must be of value.  Naked Objects frameworks can help for the “**boot strapping**” even if you have to have replace it with “hand crafted” UI  before you ship.

In most system I have worked on, there have been lots of simple **housekeeping tables**.  All these tables need a UI to edit and view them etc.  There is also great value in these simple editors being consistent.  Here a naked Objects framework could save a lot of time,  even if the main “day to day” UI is “hand crafted”

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a couple of failed projects (cases where I was brought in as a rather expensive consultant to help architect the replacement) which used the "naked objects" approach (not the framework, AFAIK) - all with simply atrocious UIs, and worked replacing a lot of the UI on one project which, in its original incarnation, had a similar approach (the entire application was a tree of objects accessed through context menus and property sheets - this was NetBeans 2.0 circa 1998 -  IDE as a giant hierarchical JavaBean).

The bottom line is, your users don't care about your architecture, they care about getting what they need to do done in the most comprehensible-to-mere-mortals set of interactions you can come up with.  If that happens to align with your architecture, you are having a lucky day - but it really is serendipity.  Trying to *force* users to care (or even know) about your architecture is a recipe for software nobody wants to use.

Code generally needs to be designed around two not-always-compatible goals:

1. Maintainability - people who didn't write the code can understand the code
2. Stability and performance - i.e. the activities the code asks the computer to physically do are both possible, and can be completed within a reasonable time frame

The abstractions and code structures that it makes sense to create to meet those two goals very, very rarely map exactly to user interface elements of any sort.  Sometimes you can get away with it - barely - if your audience is technical.  But even there, you are likely to please more users with at least a "presentation layer" adapter layer on top of the architecture that makes sense for programmers and machines.